# TableView crash issue in swift3 while adding row

Tags: swift, uitableview

Here i am tryning to add a new row but it's crashing and giving the error "attempt to insert row 3 into section 2, but there are only 3 rows in section 2 after the update". Intially the emerCount is 2 and i am trying to add 3rd row.

```
 var index = NSIndexPath()
    if (emerCount<3){
        emerCount += 1

        index = NSIndexPath(row: emerCount, section: 2)
        self.profileTableView?.insertRows(at: [index as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.profileTableView?.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- Before calling `insertRows` you have to insert the item in the data source array into the same location (index `emerCount` in section 2). This is mandatory.
- Basically **never** call `reloadData()` right after `insertRows`. Inserting the row updates the table view with an animation. Remove `reloadData()`.

Further be aware that indexes are zero-based and the third row is indeed inserted at index 2.

PS: Why is the table view optional? Is is created programmatically and displayed temporarily? And don't use `NSIndexPath` in Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks Vadian,I was not inserting the data before insertRows.

Answer (score 0):

More context is needed. What is written in your data source (`number​Of​Rows(in​Section:​)`) methods? It seems that you `number​Of​Rows(in​Section:​)` returns 3 for the section but you want to add one more row.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line : `self.profileTableView?.reloadData()`